# Google sheets script - If Else protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble inserting an `If Else` condition in my sheets script. Trying to check if protection exists by description name. If yes then skip, if no then add protection. This is my current script that adds protection only:

```
function LockFriday() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('alsdfjalsfjdlasjfl')
  spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D60'));
  var protection = spreadsheet.getRange('C8:D60').protect();
  protection.setDescription('AA Lock Friday Cells')
  .removeEditors(['email1@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com','email3.com']);
};
```

Any suggestions on how to insert If Else condition in my script?

Thank you in advance. Paul.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [What types of Questions Should I Avoid Asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You set the protection of C8:D60, are you then trying to find out if another range has the same protection?

Comment: In current script I protect a range with the description "AA Lock Friday Cells".  Another user can activate this script and lock the cells.  If a trigger or someone else tries to lock the cells again, I want to check if locked already.  If locked, ignore remainder of script, If not then execute remainder of script and lock with the description "AA Lock Friday Cells".

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following modified script close to your expected result?

#### Modified script:

```js
function LockFriday() {
  var protectRange = 'C8:D60';
  var description = 'AA Lock Friday Cells';

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('alsdfjalsfjdlasjfl');
  spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D60'));

  var p = spreadsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).find(e => e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange && e.getDescription() == description);
  if (p) return;

  var protection = spreadsheet.getRange(protectRange).protect();
  protection.setDescription(description).removeEditors(['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com', 'email3.com']);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the cells `C8:D60` have already been protected with the description of `AA Lock Friday Cells`, the script is finished. When the cells `C8:D60` have never been protected with the description of `AA Lock Friday Cells`, those cells are protected with the description of `AA Lock Friday Cells`.
- If you don't want to check the description, please modify `e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange && e.getDescription() == description` to `e.getRange().getA1Notation() == protectRange`.

#### Reference:

- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: That's it!!  Your modifications worked out perfectly!  Now only one instance of locked cells C8:D60 can exist no matter how many times the script is run.  Perfect.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I am new to this forum.  Please guide me as to how I can indicate that you helped me.  Is it just the checkmark that I need to click?  Thanks again!

Comment: @PT109 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Please guide me as to how I can indicate that you helped me.`, I think that in this case, your consideration of `Is it just the checkmark that I need to click?` is correct. Thank you, too.